# Safe way of removing elements in priority queue while ranging

Tags: go, heap, priority-queue

I took the full implementation of priority queue from [go documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__priorityQueue).
I want to remove elements if they satisfy some condition. So I should:

- iterate over queue then
- check the condition
- if condition is OK, remove element

Like this:

```
for i, value := range pq{
  if someCondtion{
    heap.Remove(&pq, i)
  }
```

}

Or for simplicity:

```
for i, value := range pq{
    heap.Remove(&pq, i)
}
```

But it is not the safe way because there is an error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.PriorityQueue.Swap(...)
main.(*PriorityQueue).Swap(0xc420088020, 0x2, 0x0)
container/heap.Remove(0x4c69a0, 0xc420088020, 0x2, 0xf, 0x0)
```

How can I properly do it?
Here is an example https://play.golang.org/p/XrQdAJIbZPw

Comment: You don't need to call any heap functions to arbitrarily remove elements from your slice. You either handle it like a slice, or through the heap functions, don't try to mix them.

Answer (score 3):

After every call to `heap.Remove` the heap is reorganized. So the initial length of `pq` gets smaller in every loop. You will reach the point when it is smaller than the current value of `i` requires it to be.

If you manipulate `pq` you must loop as it is done in the example:

```
for pq.Len() > 0 {
    item := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Item)
    fmt.Printf("%.2d:%s\n", item.priority, item.value)
}
```

see https://play.golang.org/p/Ayt4_zLo8FF

Comment: Every `heap.Pop` deletes element from queue. So it's not just iterating it 's complete clearing of queue.

Comment: What is your intention of using `heap.Remove(&pq, i)`?

Comment: I have queue of events and sometimes I should delete events not from beginning (with `heap.Pop`) but for example, from the middle it (with `heap.Remove`).

Comment: Then you should identify the exact position and remove it. But not in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not using the correct data structure or the used data structure not correctly. The idea of a queue is to put items at the end for future processing and to take items from the beginning to process them.

If you do not want to process certain items, you could either filter them before queuing or filter when they are taken from the queue before processing.

Answer (score 0):

assuming I have a `PriorityQueue` struct the wraps the `container/heap` calls and contain a `queue` which implements `heap.Interface`

```
func (pq *PriorityQueue[T]) Remove(shouldRemove func(T) bool) {
    tmpQueue := pq.queue[:0]
    for _, element := range pq.queue{
        if !shouldRemove(element) {
            tmpQueue = append(tmpQueue, element)
        }
    }
    // clear the rest of the queue to avoid memory leaks
    var zero T
    for i := len(tmpQueue); i < len(pq.queue); i++ {
        pq.queue[i] = zero
    }
    pq.queue= tmpQueue
    // re-heapify the queue
    heap.Init(pq.queue)
}
```

the filtering code comes from: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#filtering-without-allocating